# Webpack bundle is over 50 MB -- Is this normal for web pages today?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, blockchain, wallet

A question about webpack and bundling for the mobile / desktop web browser.

I was [following the instructions](https://docs.blocknative.com/onboard) to build the node package. Onboard blockchain wallet connector tool.  I also [installed webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).  After running npx webpack the Dist folder produced **94 .js files totaling 50 MB**. On connecting to index.html around 30 .js files are downloaded.

Just wondering if this is the typical output size for webpack bundles for the web browser.  I'm just looking for a decent blockchain wallet connect library to drop into my website this way visitors on mobile or desktop can interface with their installed blockchain wallet of choice.  However, 50 MB is too much.

Comment: That is _definitely_ not normal. Also note that the browser needs to expend a lot of resources just parsing these JS files.

Comment: We're not there yet. Your typical lazily coded web app is rather around 1.5 MB according to https://httparchive.org/reports/page-weight.

Answer (score -1):

- open that files and look if js is in fact minified
- remember that u can return js files zipped